# What can be used for CPVC firestops?

Tags: plumbing, code-compliance, cpvc, fireblocking

What materials to people use as a firestop for where CPVC lines penetrate through the wall/fireblocking?    According to the manufacturer, apparently CPVC does not play well with certain materials.

> "CPVC products can however be damaged by contact with chemicals found
> in some construction and ancillary products such as thread sealants,
> anti-freeze solutions, **fire stop materials**, etc."

In addition,

> DO NOT stack, support, hang equipment, or hang flexible wire/cable
> (especially communications cable), or other material on the CPVC
> system.
>
> DO NOT expose CPVC products to incompatible substances such
> as cutting oils, non-water based paints, packing oils, traditional
> pipe thread paste and dope, fungicides, termiticides, insecticides,
> detergents, building caulks, adhesive tape, solder flux, flexible
> wire/cable (with special consideration for communications cabling),
> and **non-approved spray foam insulation** materials."

Also of concern is that CPVC will expand up to 3/16" on a 10' run, so not sure it that has implications as well.

Answer (score 2):

There are fire stop caulks that are designed for use with CPVC. Just check the tube before you buy to make sure it specifies CPVC compatible.